# What's the max length of the edit summary?

Tags: discussion, edits

Not that I think I'd ever eclipse it, but just curious.

Comment: Interestingly, edits which don't change anything are discarded. My brilliant, witty, and extremely lengthy test edit summary is now lost to mankind.

Comment: @mmy: I guess it's not a big loss.

Comment: @Joh: It was mostly hype, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

300 Characters.

```
<label>Edit Summary<span class="form-error"></span></label>
<input id="edit-comment" type="text" maxlength="300" size="60" name="edit-comment" tabindex="109">
```

Comment: Same as the old comment length.